# Assigning compatible vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose you have a vector of one type that you want to assign to another of different type ?

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector ints = {0,1,2,3};
    std::vector<long long int> llints =  ints;//compile error here
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/2D9LYn)

How is this possible with a one-liner (one expression), not using lambda, using only `std` or `boost`
?

Comment: Note that you aren't _assigning_, but _initializing_ the vector in this example.

Comment: I actually meant assign, the example was bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the (surprisingly hidden) [`boost::copy_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/range/doc/utility_class.html)

```
#include <vector>
#include "boost/range/iterator_range.hpp"

int main() {
    std::vector ints = {0,1,2,3};
    auto llints = boost::copy_range<std::vector<long long int>>(ints);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to construct, you can use the [two iterator constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector<long long int> llints(ints.begin(), ints.end());
```

If you want to assign to an existing vector, you can use the two iterator [`std::vector::assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) member function:

```
std::vector<long long int> llints;
...
llints.assign(ints.begin(), ints.end());
```

Comment: suppose the vector is returned from a function, is there a way to avoid introducing a temporary variable ?

Comment: @darune You coudl just say `return vector<long long int>(ints.begin(), ints.end());`. Copies would almost certainly be elided before c++17, and I think are guaranteed to be elided since c++17.

Comment: @darune Or, just `return llints;`. I am not sure if the copy elision is guaranteed, but it will most likely take place.

Comment: its the ints / input vector thats returned from a funcion. I solved it with a temporary, theres no straightforward way to fix until maybe [tag:c++20]

Comment: @darune I'm not sure what needs "fixing". There isn't enough context. But you could ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a one-liner:

```
std::vector<long long int> llints(begin(ints), end(ints));
```

It uses the [constructor that accepts an iterator pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).